# How to register a more complex controller name as a singleton/not singleton?

Tags: ember.js

I noticed this would be a simple way to make my controller "foo" not a singleton

```
App.register('controller:foo', App.FooController, {singleton: false });
```

But if I have a more complex controller name, what would I put in the register? Say something like this ...

```
App.WidgetsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use camelCase, this is the same with needs etc throughout the app (despite it allowing some others as well)

```
App.register('controller:widgetsNew', App.WidgetsNewController, {singleton: false });
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/viboc/3/edit